# Retrieving text from within div using node.js

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

I am currently trying to write a scraper that will get all the 'p' tags from within a div inside a facebook post using node.js

Each of the posts on the page lie within div's that all have this class: .text_exposed_root

There is sometimes multiple 'p' tags within each post so ideally i need to grab all of the html text within that div if possible. I am using cheerio and request modules and my code so far is below:

```
request(BTTS, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body), 
        post = $(".text_exposed_root p").text();

        console.log(post);
    } else {
        console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
    }
})
```

I have tried using .text .value and .html but they all just return a blank response. I'm guessing I would need to grab all the 'p' tags within that div and convert to a string maybe?

Thanks in advance.

EDITED:

```
var url = ('https://www.facebook.com/BothTeamsToScore');

request({url:url, headers: headers}, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error){

        var strippedBody = body.replace(/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/g, "")

        console.log(strippedBody);

        var $ = cheerio.load(strippedBody), 
        post = $(".text_exposed_root p").text();

        console.log(post);
    } else {
        console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you're going to need to set some headers with your request. Without them, Facebook will respond with and "unsupported browser" page. That's your first problem.

```
var headers = {
   'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36',
   'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

var url = BTTS

request({url:url, headers: headers}, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error){
        var $ = cheerio.load(body.replace(/<!--|-->/g, ''))
        console.log($('.text_exposed_root p').text())
    } else {
        console.log("We’ve encountered an error: " + error);
    }
})
```

The other thing that should be noted, is that the content comes in inside of an html comment. ie

```
<code class="hidden_elem"><!-- 
... 
    <div class="text_exposed_root">
        <p>text</p>
```

Cheerio will not parse comment nodes, so you'll most likely need to remove the `<!--` and `-->` and load the result back into cheerio to parse the part of html that you want. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Jordan. I added in a regex to remove the comments and attempted to pass that back in but the console.log(post) is blank?? Edited original post with new code.

Comment: @Paul'Macca'McGill Your problem is that your regular exp removes the whole comment. We only want to remove the comment tags, but keep the contents within them (that's where the html lies that you are searching). Find my edited answer above. It should be what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. I've got it returning results now however my jquery selector doesn't seem to work. I want to select the first class where the text contained inside only contains certain words and then get all the p's within it. 

'console.log($('.text_exposed_root:first-child p').text()); '

This will return me the first post but then all the p tags within the posts after it as well. Also tried the below but then it just returned blank.

'console.log($('.text_exposed_root:first-child:contains("£25 - 1K Challenge -") p').text());'

Comment: Read the documentation for cheerio https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#each-functionindex-element- . There is a function .each() to help you iterate over each matched element. Then you can store the text in an array or something. The documentation provides an example that's probably pretty close to what you're looking for.